# Game force closing at various times. Need help Interpreting logCat warnings and errors

Tags: android, logcat

My game starts with a splash screen and plays music until someone touches the screen or the given amount of time expires. It then goes to the menu activity which has two buttons, one to start the game and another to open an about activity that pops up a transparent window telling the user about the game.

My current problem is that sometimes when I start the game I get a force close right away, or when I touch the screen to skip the splash, when I press start to play the game, and even in this errors specific case I pressed the about button. The weird thing for me is that sometimes everything works.

I am getting a lot of these errors even if it works, I just need some help interpreting them so I can fix 'em. I am not sure at which point I started getting these force closes because it was consistently working before. I've always had errors though and I don't want something unstable.

If you need additional info to help, you know where I am. :D

Thanks and I can't wait to get this application back on track so I can work on features!!

**Errors below are the result of running my game and at the main menu pressing about and getting a force close.**

```
 09-11 20:54:53.984: WARN/AudioFlinger(34): write blocked for 82 msecs, 23 delayed writes, thread 0xb3f0
    09-11 20:54:55.314: WARN/TimedEventQueue(34): Event 15 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?
    09-11 20:54:55.314: ERROR/MediaPlayer(302): stop called in state 1
    09-11 20:54:55.314: ERROR/MediaPlayer(302): error (-38, 0)
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
    09-11 20:54:55.354: ERROR/global(302):     at com.ss.game.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:61)
    09-11 20:55:22.915: WARN/TimedEventQueue(34): Event 2 was not found in the queue, already cancelled?
    09-11 20:55:22.925: WARN/dalvikvm(302): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.ss.game/com.ss.game.MyMenu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3348)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3305)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3288)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2500(ActivityThread.java:125)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2040)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at com.ss.lastzombie.MyMenu.onPause(MyMenu.java:78)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:3842)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1190)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3335)
    09-11 20:55:22.945: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(302):     ... 12 more
    09-11 20:55:23.477: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{43fea4f8 com.ss.game/.MyMenu}
    09-11 20:55:32.984: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
    09-11 20:55:33.454: WARN/InputManagerService(59): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 302 uid 10032
```

Comment: There is a null pointer exception at MyMenu.java:78. That's it.

Comment: @Cristian why doesn't it force close every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with this:

```
ERROR/MediaPlayer(302): stop called in state 1
```

MediaPlayer wants it's methods to be called in particular order. See the state diagram: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

It seems you are calling it in `idle` (1) state: http://androidxref.com/2.2.3/xref/frameworks/base/include/media/mediaplayer.h#111

Comment: That source says it needs to be initialized correct? How exactly would I go about doing that. Currently I just use mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound); Then I use mpSplash.start(); Do I need code between the create and start? I tried prepare but that seems to do the same thing as start but requires things to be passed to it? after I use start I eventually use .stop() and .reset() in a sub thread (splash screen timer thread). If you want to see the code i have exactly here is a link to my other thread question that has it. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7381637/625740

Comment: Does the media play? It seems that the problem is when you call stop().

Comment: yes the media plays and stops, I am just looking to find out why I have errors.

Comment: It seem like you are calling `stop()` two times in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it is related to the Media Player issue...

What seem more important for me is this :
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.ss.lastzombie.MyMenu.onPause(MyMenu.java:78)

I would check the MyMenu.java file, line 78 and find what pointer can be null at this point...

Comment: I fixed the NullPointerException and the Thread errors. I am still having a Media Player issue though.