# Splash screen thread throwing errors. How to resolve? (Code & Errors Included)

Tags: android, audio, thread-safety, splash-screen

I have some errors with my splash screen that I have been working on for a while and can't figure out. Is there a better way to time my splash screen than a thread? What's wrong with my current thread? Can you see an issue with my media player object?

I've posted the guts of my splash class. Hopefully I can get some direction on these issues. This works when I run the app but I just don't want to have errors.

**-------------------------Code------------------------------**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 ......onCreate, hide window, and setting content view.......
        // Play Sound for startup
        mpSplash = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.splashscream);
        mpSplash.start();
        final Splash splash = this;
        logoTimer = new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    // Wait given period of time or exit on touch
                    wait(4500);
                }
            } 
            catch(InterruptedException ex){ 
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            finish();
            mpSplash.stop();
            mpSplash.reset();
            //mpSplash.release();
            //mpSplash.release();
            // Run next activity
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(splash, Game.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            stop();
        }
    };
    logoTimer.start();
}
// Splash screen touch events
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent evt)
{
    if(evt.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        // Stop the introduction sounds
        mpSplash.stop();
        mpSplash.reset();
        //mpSplash.release();
        //mpSplash.release();
        synchronized(logoTimer){
            logoTimer.notifyAll();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**------------------------------Errors-----------------------------**

```
09-11 21:50:04.644: ERROR/MediaPlayer(460): stop called in state 1
09-11 21:50:04.644: ERROR/MediaPlayer(460): error (-38, 0)
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460): Deprecated Thread methods are not supported.
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460):     at java.lang.VMThread.stop(VMThread.java:85)
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1379)
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460):     at java.lang.Thread.stop(Thread.java:1344)
09-11 21:50:04.654: ERROR/global(460):     at com.ss.lastzombie.Splash$1.run(Splash.java:61)
```

Thanks!!

Comment: The errors are not in context; the line numbers indicate where the error is occurring.  You need to point out which is Splash.java:61 in your code.

Comment: @Charles Line 61 is startActivity(intent);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't call `stop()` in your thread. That's a deprecated method (it leads to instability in the VM) and is not needed. (The thread will exit when the `run()` method returns). You probably intended to call `finish()` for the splash activity. That would make sense.

Just for form's sake, you might want to call `startActivity` and `finish` on the main thread instead of your worker thread. To do this, post a Runnable using `runOnUIThread()` and call those two methods from the Runnable.

Comment: removing stop() fixed my thread error! Thanks. Now onto the second part of your answer. Can you explain the reasoning for using runOnUIThread()? Can you explain what exactly a "runnable" is? I am a bit new and just trying to understand. Thanks!!!

Comment: [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) is an interface that defines a single method: `void run();`. Any object that is declared to implement Runnable can be used in a variety of places in Java, and in Android in particular. For instance, you can create a Thread with `new Thread(aRunnable).start()` instead of subclassing Thread itself. For information about running on the UI thread, read the article [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html).